# Vue Element not being rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey I am using Vue + Laravel and using webpack.mix for package control.

Currently, stuck on a peculiar issue. I am trying to render  component in my app.js file.

App.js

```
Vue.component('navigation',require ('./views/navigation.vue'));
Vue.component('Example', require('./components/Example.vue')); //this works
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    navigation
  }
});
```

Php Blade File where component is being rendered.

```
<body>

    <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
            <navigation></navigation>
        </div>         
    </div>
```

And my navigation component

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
       toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-
       controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

As the example component comes out of the box so it works, but the navigation component spits out this error.

app.js:814 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My nav component is correct as i export the script aswell using

<script>
  export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

No need to register your component twice. Remove `components` section and simply add `Vue.component` before the instance. Like this

Try this

**app.js**

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

Vue.component('navigation', require ('./views/navigation.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**views/navigation.vue**

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" 
                        class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-target="#navbar" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="navbar"
                >
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey,

i have already tried that.

But it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Sam i have tried the exact same code of my answer in my laravel project and it renders the component just fine.

Comment: I'm really confused maybe i might create a new project :/

Comment: Posting the solution anyway, my vue file was not being updated so make sure to include --watch-poll if running npm watch and disable cache in your browser.